# Open and show windows command prompt to user inside Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

How would I go about opening the windows command prompt, then sending a command to it and showing it to the user inside my Qt application?

I know you can send commands to the command prompt and get output *behind the scenes* without showing the command prompt to the user, but I want the user to be able to interact with the command prompt window and send their own commands.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed:

```
QProcess CommandPrompt;
QStringList Arguments;

Arguments << "/K" << "echo" << "hello";
CommandPrompt.startDetached("cmd",Arguments);
```